# How Can I Screenshot a Webpage Object By It's ID Locator?

Tags: powershell

An example of what I'm trying to do with Powershell.

Take this [Huffpost page](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/celebrity/). 
The ID of the top image is : headline_image

I'd like to get its size and position, then screen cap it.

I've read that [Javascript functions could be called from Powershell](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2014/03/09/calling-a-javascript-function-from-powershell-using-jint/), but I don't understand if I need Jint or how to install it, if I do. I haven't found the required .dll files.

Comment: I can't actually test right now, but [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/03/17/downloading-images-from-webpages.aspx) might be what you need.

Comment: That is useful for downloadable images, but I need something that works in instances where the display isn't an image file - and that can work with any browser (or, at least Firefox).